# What is the appropriate one?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax

I want to download datastax which has solr and cassandra. I endup with [this link](http://downloads.datastax.com/enterprise/).

```
  datastax-enterprise
  datastax-agent
  dse
```

I know what is opscenter. But i don't know which one should i download and what is the difference between these three? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

DSE is short for Datastax Enterprise

datastax-agent is the agent that runs in all of your nodes so they can be monitored/controlled by opscenter

datastax-enterprise will include all you need (spark/solr/cassandra/etc)

for more data you can look at http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/install/installGUI.html

PS: if your using EC2 i would suggest using opscenter to install dse right from the datastax AMI